# En Scilab al hacer un "plot" se cierra el programa con el siguiente error

Tags: plot, scilab

> A fatal error has been detected by Scilab.
> Please check your user-defined functions (or external module ones) should they appear in the stack trace.
> Otherwise you can report a bug on http://bugzilla.scilab.org/ with:
>
> - a sample code which reproduces the issue
> - the result of [a, b] = getdebuginfo()
> - the following information:
>
>   [jose-LT25:13595] Signal: Violación de segmento (11)
>   [jose-LT25:13595] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
>   [jose-LT25:13595] Failing at address: 0x26
>
>   Call stack:
>   1: 0xbde262 <JVM_handle_linux_signal>        (/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/lib/server/libjvm.so)
>   2: 0xbd112c < >                              (/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/lib/server/libjvm.so)
>   3: 0x153c0  < >                              (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0)
>   4: 0x1eb762 < >                              (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i915_dri.so)
>   5: 0x1ebdc3 < >                              (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i915_dri.so)
>   6: 0x10cc59 < >                              (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i915_dri.so)
>   7: 0x1dad4c < >                              (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i915_dri.so)
>   8: 0x1dca76 < >                              (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i915_dri.so)
>   9: 0x1d140c < >                              (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i915_dri.so)
>   10: 0x11f08c < >                              (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i915_dri.so)
>   11: 0x1d0804 < >                              (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i915_dri.so)
>   12: 0x2dcdd9 < >                              (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i915_dri.so)
>   13: 0x2dc191 < >                              (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i915_dri.so)
>   14: 0x61341  <Java_jogamp_opengl_gl4_GL4bcImpl_dispatch_1glDrawArrays1__IIIJ> (/usr/lib/jni/libjogl_desktop.so)
>   15: ?        ?                                (?)
>   End of stack

Por ejemplo con el siguiente código:

```
    set(gda(), "grid_style",[7 7], "grid", [1 1]*color("grey70"));
    title(gda(), "fontsize", 3, "color", "lightseagreen", "fontname", "helvetica bold");
    
    x = linspace(1e-1,100,1000);
    xm = 35;
    dx = 17;
    G = exp(-((x-xm)/dx).^2/2)*30;
    
    scf(1); clf
    subplot(2,2,1), plot(x, G),       title("plot(x, y)")
    subplot(2,2,2), plot("ln", x, G), title("semilog-x : plot(""ln"", x, y)")
    gca().sub_ticks(1) = 8;
    subplot(2,2,3), plot("nl", x, G), title("semilog-y : plot(""nl"", x, y)")
    gca().sub_ticks(2) = 8;
    subplot(2,2,4), plot("ll", x, G), title("loglog : plot(""ll"", x, y)")
    gca().sub_ticks = [8 8];
    
    sda();
```

Comment: Suena a un lío feo de uso de recursos debajo de tu código. Puedes revisar si esta respuesta en askubuntu te sirve? https://askubuntu.com/questions/928732/scilab-6-0-0-segmentation-fault-core-dumped-on-start

Comment: Hola. Probé lo que dice en ese enlace, obtengo el mismo resultado.